# Is there a "using" in Python?

Tags: python-3.7

It's tiring and not concise to call "class.function()" every single time. Is there a way I can just use "function()" to call the function in a class? I'm using Python 3.7.

```
class SineModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    ...
    def np_to_tensor(list_of_numpy_objs):
        result = (tf.convert_to_tensor(obj) for obj in list_of_numpy_objs)
        return result
```

```
def eval_sine_test(model, optimizer, x, y, x_test, y_test, num_steps=(0, 1, 10)):
    tensor_x_test, tensor_y_test = SineModel.np_to_tensor((x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Way too bug-prone. Javascript has this functionality, and found it to be a mistake they never should have put in. It's disabled in strict mode.

Comment: `np_to_tensor` should be a static method (since you are calling it as such anyway) or a standalone function, as it doesn't appear to make any use of any instance of `SineModel`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't defining the method correctly (nor does there appear to be any reason for it to be a method in the first place). (Well, that's a little harsh. As long as you only call the function via the class, and not an instance, there is little difference between what is technically meant as an instance method and a proper static method).

That said, you barely need to define a specific function for this.

```
def eval_sine_test(model, optimizer, x, y, x_test, y_test, num_steps=(0, 1, 10)):
    tensor_x_test, tensor_y_test = map(tf.convert_to_tensor, x_test, y_test)
    ...
```

If you really want a function inside the namespace of the class, define a `staticmethod`:

```
class SineModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def np_to_tensor(*objs):
        result = (tf.convert_to_tensor(obj) for obj in obj)
        return result
```

```
def eval_sine_test(model, optimizer, x, y, x_test, y_test, num_steps=(0, 1, 10)):
    tensor_x_test, tensor_y_test = SineModel.np_to_tensor(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Thank you I will make it static. But for a function that is in SineModel, is there a way to not specifically write "SineModel." every time when you call it?

Comment: No, there is not. Consider it a reminder to only define a static method if you have a really, really good reason to include it in the class.

Comment: (I mean, ignoring the option of defining your own shorter alias like `to_tensor = SineModel.np_to_tensor` if you plan on using it a lot.)